# PHP SELECT WHERE DATETIME AND TEXT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

```
$result = $this->database->query(printf("SELECT * FROM 'events' WHERE ('date_time' = \"%s %s\" AND 'title' = \"%s\")", $date, $time, $title));
```

Results in:

```
SELECT * FROM 'events' WHERE ('date_time' = "2013-12-06 18:00:00" AND 'title' = "Viikate, The Mutants");SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "106": syntax error
```

Tried with `;` in query and without, with parenthesis in query and without.

Comment: Dont use single quotes for field names. Use the backtick operator "`"

Comment: There is not `106` in this query. This error comes from another query.

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quote `'` around your table column names which is not correct. Wrap your column names around backticks  or do not wrap them at all. I prefer using backticks `` ` ``  to separate the column names.

```
$result = $this->database->query(printf("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE (`date_time` = \"%s %s\" AND `title` = \"%s\")", $date, $time, $title));
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put ' around table and column names. Either use ` or nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf`, `printf` is function to console out.
And your query also needs to be modified to use backtick(`) to enclose table or field name.

ie)

```
SELECT * FROM \`events\` WHERE (\`date_time\` = \"%s %s\" AND \`title\` = \"%s\")
```